# Jenkins error: TF30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2013, tfs, ant

I am trying to check in files into Microsoft Visual Studio TFS from jenkins using the tf.exe check in command. The command works fine when executed from a command prompt in windows but when i incorporate the commands in a .bat file and invoke through ANT scripts in Jenkins i am getting the below error. Could you please let us know what probably might be the issue?

On another note the same credentials are being used in the jenkins job to get files from TFS successfully.

### Error:

TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://<>:8080/tfs/<>

### Bat file:

cd %1
tf workspaces /collection:http://<>:8080/tfs/<> login:<>,<>
tf add %2
tf checkin /noprompt

Comment: Are you using the `Execute Windows batch command` and `Invoke ANT` in Build section of a Jenkins item?

Comment: No...i am invoking the .bat file from Ant script and im calling the Ant script from Jenkins. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have created the authentication link between the TFS instance and the system profile. Jenkins, running in that user profile context, should then be able to issue TF commands and create workspaces, check in codes.

You could follow below tutorial to generate Credentials, create build item. [How to setup automated builds using Jenkins and Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://www.aisoftwarellc.com/blog/post/how-to-setup-automated-builds-using-jenkins-and-visual-studio-team-foundation-server/2044)  Suggest you to create [Global configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin), after configuring  your team project collection, this will use automatic credentials configuration with the TFVC SCM. If you configure Jenkins use the alternate credentials, then every command that you pass must include the same creds.

Comment: Hello Patrick...i already have authorized credentials to TFS from Jenkins job. Using this jenkins job i am able to get the files from TFS server as well but when i invoke the above batch file (which checks-in file into TFS) from Ant script (which is part of the same jenkins job) i am getting unauthorised error. Hope this clarifies

Comment: @DP Why you use a .bat file in Ant scipt for the translation, you could directly call tf.exe in your ANT script. Just configure the environment variable "Path" for tf.exe, then you can access to tf command directly from your ANT script. Details please refer this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: @Dp Suggest you also try to use `Execute Windows batch command` in the jenkins job to call your batch file ,see if get the same error message, this will narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Dp  Any update on this issue, have you figured it out?